# What's the purpose of '.' when importing classes from another py file?

Tags: python, package, python-module

I have created 2 Python files and it's saved in the `OOP_1` folder. There are errors when I tried to run and I am unable to understand the purpose of using `.` when importing the classes from Python files.

I have tried removing the `.student`, `.course`, from the relevant Python files, but it wouldn't run in `main.py` using the `from OOP_1 import *`.

1. `student.py`

   ```
   class Student:
       def __init__(self,name, number):
           self._student_name = name
           self._student_number = number
   ```
2. `course.py`

   ```
   from .student import Student

   class Course(Student):
       #instance attributes
       def __init__(self, name, code, credit, student_limit):
           # Your code for the constructor
           self._name = name
           self._code = code
           self._credit = credit
           self._student_limit = student_limit
   ```
3. `__init__.py`

   ```
   from .student import Student
   from .course import Course
   ```
4. `main.py`

   ```
   from OOP_1 import *
   ```

However, in `__init__`, the Python gives me an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.student'; '__main__' is not a package
```

In `main.py`, Python gives me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'course'
```

What can I do to ensure that my folder where I stored my classes will work in `main.py` file?

Comment: Can you add your folder/file structure to your question

Answer (score 1):

> [A single leading dot indicates a relative import, starting with the
>   current package.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports)

You need to have those modules in the current context to import them like this